# What does the phrase "I wish I could meet you so bad" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can you help me to understand this phrase:

> I wish I could meet you so bad.

Comment: @Polli  He is expressing his pain and longing to meet you.  It is the pain you feel when you want something so badly that it torments you.  It is a complement to you.

Comment: Can you please add a little more context to your question? Where did you see this? What part of it don't you understand? If we know what's confusing you, it's easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't interpret bad, as a negative thing here. When the person says they want to meet you so bad, they mean they really want to meet you. Not that the manner in which they want to meet you, is a negative thing.

Comment: I think one should explain that this colloquial "so bad" means "very much"  and refers to "I wish", not to "meet you". Very slangy style.

Answer (score 2):

The idiom "so bad" should be taken to mean "very intensely and urgently", and generally applies to wanting, desiring, or needing.  As in "I have to go to the bathroom so bad."

Comment: Could it be used with « to love » as in « I love so bad(ly) »?

Comment: @nakhli, I think it would be a little weird to use it just to modify "love", perhaps because English speakers rarely talk about their capacity or tendency to love in the abstract.  But "I love _you_ so bad" is [perfectly intelligible to native speakers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPvhItA3lIM).

Answer (score 1):

The *bad* should be understood as an adverb, and 'corrected' (apologies to Americans) to *badly*.

A slight re-ordering of words then gives *"I wish so badly (that) I could meet you"*.

The use of the word *bad* itself is well explained by @A Prejean